# how to work with button in class and packages at AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, package

I am a beginner of action script. working with button in action script class file not working.
i have created two file one is **stream.as** and another is **main.as**
main.as is the main class file of my frame. 
i have drawed a button and converted it in button and gave instance name play_btn. 
but the compiler giving me 1120: access of undefined property play_btn.
the both codes are given below;
**main.as**

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import stream.stream;
public class main extends stream {
    public function main() {
        }
        // constructor code
    }
}
```

**stream.as**

```
package {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class stream extends MovieClip {
    public function main() {
        play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pausevedio);
        function pausevedio(event:MouseEvent):void{
            play_btn.visible=false;
        }
        // constructor code
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As a note, you should name your classes with a capital letter, eg. Main, Stream. The constructor for class stream should be stream(), not main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it's because the play_btn belongs solely to your main class and you're trying to access it through the stream class, to do this properly try to instantiate it through code in the class you wish to use it in instead of on the timeline like so:

```
playBtn: play_btn = new play_btn();
playBtn.x = x;
playBtn.y = y;
addChild(playBtn);
```

This is my best guess I'm not exactly sure how your classes are structured but this might be your issue. I hope this helps (I'm new too but I figured my two-cents might help!)!

~Cheers!